# c++: move cursor in console with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, console, cursor

I'm working in xcode under Mac system.

I want to simulate [falling code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpWrtXyEAN0) in console with c++.

My design is that each falling code chain is an object, which has a function containing system API to move the cursor. With multithreading, I can simulate some falling code chains.

Here is my code:

```
// CodeChain.h
class CodeChain
{
public:
    CodeChain(int, int);
    void setx(int);
    void sety(int);
    void show();
    std::thread threadShow();
private:
    char codes[256];
    int x, y;
};


//CodeChain.cpp
CodeChain::CodeChain(int ax, int ay) : x(ax), y(ay)
{
    codes[0] = 'a';
    codes[1] = 'b';
    codes[2] = 'c';
    codes[3] = 'd';
    codes[4] = '\0';
}

void CodeChain::show()
{
    int i = 0;
    char ch;
    int n = 0;
    while (true) {
        move(x + n - 1, y);
        printw("%c", ' ');
        i = 0;
        while ((ch = codes[i]) != '\0') {
            move(x + i + n, y);
            printw("%c", ch);
            ++i;
        }
        n++;
        refresh();
        sleep(1);
    }
}

std::thread CodeChain::threadShow()
{
    return std::thread([=] { show(); });
}


void CodeChain::setx(int ax)
{
    x = ax;
}

void CodeChain::sety(int ay)
{
    y = ay;
}


// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {   
    initscr();
    start_color();

    CodeChain cc0(5, 1);
    CodeChain cc1(5, 2);

    std::thread t0 = cc0.threadShow();
    std::thread t1 = cc1.threadShow();

    t0.join();
    t1.join();


    return 0;
}
```

If there is only one object of CodeChain, meaning that only one thread is run, it works. I can see a falling code chain.

However, if I add a thread, just like the code above, everything will be massed up. I can see codes everywhere. It seems that I got a synchronized problem but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
move(x + i + n, y)
printw("%c", ch);
```

The two lines must be locked. Otherwise there will be a synchro problem.